# jquery live fastfilter (1.03) - CRASHING

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, filter, crash

i have a huge list of names, which i would like to "filter live". jquery live fastfilter
does that: 
http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/

It does that for me too. But when you "filter down" (means, delete chars, to make the search broader again) it always crashes. It does not with the demo-data. With mine it does. Any Idea? Here is the Fiddle with the original data to reproduce [try "nabokov" for example, it's names of Russians in the Berlin of the 20's]:

The code won't help:

```
$('#search_input').fastLiveFilter('#search_list', {
    timeout: 200
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wp8bJ/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me with FF, no errors.

Comment: @LastCoder, i always tried with Chrome, where it crashes when you backspace character by character. You are right, in firefox it's not perfectly smooth, but it does NOT crash. Any Idea what's wrong with Chrome?

Comment: Same problem here using chrome. No console error message. I would suggest you trying to debug plugin source to see what is making it crash. Search where minimum characters length is set and logic behind this, bug should be not far. Although in official site, it works on chrome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: exactly!

Comment: This is a bug in Chromes JS or rendering engine. If you strip out all of the jQuery and use straight JS in the fiddle the hang still occurs, if you turn the setTimeout into an always running setInterval, the hang still occurs.